# Как задать id для тега mark?

Tags: css

Просьба подсказать, как задать `id` для тега `mark`?

В CSS есть такой код `mark1 {несколько строк кода}`, не получается задать `id`.

То есть, что бы не указывал, не работает: ни `#%id% mark1`, ни просто `%id%mark1`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
[id="%id%"] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="%id%">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ! Но надо именно с %id%. Этот id назначает программа (её плагин) при создании страницы. То есть, если на странице будет несколько элементов с тегом mark, то каждый должен быть с разным id, чтобы к каждому можно было применить разные стили (цвет и так далее).

Comment: @Plutooo, не совсем понятно, но попробуйте еще вот так 
`[id="%id%"]`, обновила ответ

Comment: `mark1` это класс или ... добавили бы html код чтобы было понятнее

Comment: @Plutooo боюсь, без более подробной информации об этой программе и о том, как она работает и откуда каким образом берёт id, как-то внятно помочь вряд ли получится

Comment: Спасибо за ответы и советы! В html будет выглядеть как <mark1>Текст</mark1>, а css будут стили для этого текста. Сделал немного по-другому, вроде работает.